# Why does my Android 10 phone needs to be called multiple times before rining?

Tags: calls

My Nokia 7.2 Android 10 phone has the following strange problem that is 100% reproducible:

1. Sits there doing nothing for 10 or 20 minutes.
2. Receives a phone call but does not ring.
3. Receives another phone call soon without ringing.
4. Receives another phone call soon without ringing.
5. Receives another phone call and rings finally. It will continue to ring if a phone call is received soon.

Again, the above can be reproduced reliably.  Could anyone offer a tip on how to fix this?

Comment: This is somehow reminded me of a feature in "Do Not Disturb" mode. Are you using it? Otherwise, have you checked the settings inside the Phone app?

Comment: I had never heard of this feature.  I have just checked the settings and you are right - it was turned on.  I do not know how this happened.  Could you turn your comment into an answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 0):

I've had that issue with my older phone (a Samsung) at my home office and my new phone (a Pixel 5a) seems to have the same problem.

I think that in my case it is because the phone is not accepting WiFi calls automatically and I have a bad connection to the cell tower (I'm in a canyon so the antenna is just not properly positioned).

The one way I've found to *fix* this (At least temporarily) is to make a call to my landline and hang up. That will wake up the *call over WiFi* feature and then it works well.

---

As mentioned in a comment under the question, the other reason might be the "Do No Disturb" feature. That was not my issue, though.

Answer (score 0):

**This is caused by the "Do Not Disturb" mode and its "allows repeat callers" feature.**

The "Do Not Disturb" mode can prevent interruptions from all phone calls, though some contacts can be whitelisted, and may also allow repeat callers to interrupt the user.

The setting can be accessed from Settings - Sound & vibration - Do Not Disturb - People - Calls - Allow repeat callers.

> **Allow repeat callers**
>
> If the same person calls a second time within a 15-minute period

To prevent the first (few) call suppression, turn off the Do Not Disturb mode.